# html - image changing on li / a hover

Tags: html, css, tags

I have encountered a very interesting problem about img src which change on a:hover.

[SCREENSHOT](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/7038/sywe.png)

As you see, hovering the `<a>` sector,you cant see logically the white img. So I had the same icons on black and white, I want on hovering the sectors of #menu, the img src changes img links to black icons, instead of white, which are for only non-hovered sectors.

CSS+HTML: http://paste.laravel.com/KJ1

Comment: you cant swap an img src with css, you have to either use javascript, or put the image as a css background-image (best solution imo)

Comment: Would suggest using a CSS sprite instead: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ul li a{
 background:#000000 url(/path/to/white/icon) left no-repeat;
 background-color:black;
}
ul li a:hover{
 background:#FFFFFF url(/path/to/black/icon) left no-repeat;
}
```

try this one

Comment: Used ur method, its changes the icon, but the white bg dont work, hovering the sectors :((

Comment: Works! Thanks, but, how to control the icon position? I mean pixels left/right.

Comment: Its dissapears when had more than 1 position parametre, but works with 1

Answer (score 0):

Please see this below example. it's shows how to change the background image of li on mouseover event.

[change background image of li on an a:hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101215/change-background-image-of-li-on-an-ahover)

Hope it help.

Comment: Well, Its changes only sectors bg, not icon?

Comment: You can use this same method in the icon tag or icon container.

Answer (score 0):

You could use background image sprites for this there is an article about sprites here: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ this will also reduce server calls to get images as all images can be in a single file.

CSS Example:

```
ul li a{
   background: #000000 url('sprite.png') no-repeat;
}
ul li a:hover{
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

//then classes for each different link

ul li a.home {
   //white icon
   background-position: 0 0; 
}
ul li a.home:hover {
   //black icon
   background-position: 0 -20px;
}
```