# Multiple targets and effects for CSS hover

Tags: css, hover, transition, target

i have looked at other questions here and tried variations of code, but nothing seems to affect my outcome: nothing works but the hover background change on the element being hovered.

ideally, the code would produce the effect of changing the background image of the element being hovered, but also move a separate div with transition.

here is my Css for both the hover div (like a mouseover effect button) and the div i want to move on hover.

the idea is a sliding effect in and out for the div, while the "button" has an active and passive state:

```
#custom-div-welcome2 {
background: transparent;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 53px;
width: 325px;
height: 385px;
overflow: auto;
z-index: 0;
transition: top 2s;
-webkit-transition: top 2s;
}

#custom-div-AboutButton a{
background: transparent url(junk.png) no-repeat;
position: absolute;
left:710px;
top: 325px;
width: 115px;
height: 22px;
z-index: 1;
}

#custom-div-AboutButton a:hover {
background: transparent url(stuff.png) no-repeat;
}

#custom-div-AboutButton a:hover #custom-div-welcome2{
top: 180px;
}
```

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101215/change-background-image-of-li-on-an-ahover

Comment: currently for backwards compatibility your best bet it to make sure any elements that need to be effected by a hover state are children of the hovered element, as sibling and parent selectors can be.. iffy to deal with.. can you provide your html please

Comment: ah i see. well, thing is, it's on a site that only allows editing of CSS not of the HTML, for a profile i was trying to make for someone. oh well then, if it can't be done, i'll try something else